# Mobile touch show and hide div

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a script where I can touch an image to show a div and touch when is visible and hide again. When I touch it shows and hides at the same time. I know why,but I just don´t know how to make it to work to stay showing once I touch once and then it hides once I touch again.  The issue I have is that obviousbly it makes it work the two functions to show and hide sequencelly. This is what I tried:

html

```
<div id="box1">
<div class="boxesBubble bubble1">
<a href="http://iarabrows.pt/novo2/threading">Threading &#8690;</a><br>
<a href="http://iarabrows.pt/novo2/threading">Sobrancelhas &#8690;</a><br>
<a href="http://iarabrows.pt/novo2/threading">Pestanas &#8690;</a><br>
<a href="http://iarabrows.pt/novo2/threading">Limpeza de pele &#8690;</a><br>
<a href="http://iarabrows.pt/novo2/threading">Peeling &#8690;</a><br>
</div>
<div id="boxes" class="img1">
<img class="imageBoxes" src="images/face.jpg"/>
<div class="arrow_box">
<div id="boxTitle">
Face
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

script

```
$('.img1').on('mouseover touch', function () {

   $('.bubble1').show(200);

});
$('#box1').on('mouseleave click touch', function () {

   if($('.bubble1').is(':visible')){
   $('.bubble1').hide(200);
   }

});
```

tried also this approach but shows and hides for a split second

```
$('#box1').on('touch', function () {
   if($('.bubble1').is(':visible') == true ){

       $('.bubble1').hide(200);

    } else {

       $('.bubble1').show(200);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `toggle`?

```
$('.bubble1').toggle(200);
```

Comment: a.) did you include jQuery mobile? b.) If yes and it still doesn't work, try with "tap" instead of "touch"

Comment: The touch works ok, The issue I have is how to make a jquery that when I touch stays visible, and touch again and it hides.I tried also with variables and it stays showing, but does't hide. The issue I have is that obviousbly it makes it work the two functions to show and hide sequencelly.